# ¿como leer caracter por caracter en java?

Tags: java

Disculpen tengo una duda, tengo que realizar una clase que lea de un .txt calificaciones e imprima el nombre del alumno con el promedio mas alto, el problema es que solo se leer linea por linea y no se como al leer caracter por caracter pueda hacer que lea una calificacion de 2-3 digitos y las guarde en una variable al igual que el nombre

El documento debe estar asi

Alarcón 75 80 90 50 75 100

Galicia 50 75 50

Valencia 80 95 50 100

de ahi debe leer las calificaciones y sacar el promedio e imprimir en pantalla el nombre del alumno con la calificacion mas alta

lo unico que tengo es esta clase que hice pero es para leer linea por linea

```
    public static String[]   cargarArreglo (InputStream is, int n) throws IOException{
    int i=0;
    int j = 0;
      String [] v = new String [n];
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader (is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (isr);
    String linea = br.readLine();
    while ((linea != null) && (i <n)) {
        v[i] = linea;
        linea=br.readLine();
        i++;


    }
    br.close();
      for(j =0;j<n;j++){
            System.out.println(v[j]);

          }

    return v;
}
```

Comment: parsea cada linea a partir del caracter " " (espacio), eso debe quedar en un arreglo, luego pasa a entero todos esos elementos, luego agarra todos esos enteros y los trabajas para sacar el promedio.

Comment: Lee la línea normal, luego haz **linea.split(" ")** esto le devuelve un arreglo de strings del cual ya sabes la posición [0] es el nombre, luego los otros son los valores ya con eso puedes hacer el calculo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tienes que leer caracter por caracter para conseguir lo que necesitas. Leyendo linea por línea, como lo haces, vas bien, solo debes utilizar el método `split()` de la clase `String` para separar las claficaciones y el nombre. Solo debes tener en cuenta que, según ejemplo de la estructura del documento que compartes, cada alumno puede tener una cantidad variables de calificaciones, por lo que te recomiendo crear una clase `Alumno` que maneje el nombre de cada alumno y una lista de sus notas; y que a partir de esta clase desarrolles los mecanismos para obtener los datos que necesitas.

```
public class Alumno {
    private String nombre;
    private List<int> calificaciones;// pongo int porque tu ejemplo muestra números enteros solamente

    public Alumno(String nombre, List<int> calificaciones) {
        // Notar que no valido los parámetros pero deben validarse
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.calificaciones = calificaciones;
    }

    // Métodos getters y setters
}


public static List<Alumno> cargarAlumnos(InputStream is) throws IOException {       
    List<Alumno> alumnosList = new ArrayList();        

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader (is);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (isr);
    String linea = br.readLine();

    List<int> calificacionesList = null;
    while (linea != null) {
        String[] lineaDividida = linea.split(" "); 

        calificacionesList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < lineaDividida.length; i++) {
            calificacionesList.add(Integer.parseInt(lineaDividida[i]));
        }

        alumnosList.add(new Alumno(lineaDividida[0], calificacionesList));

        linea = br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();

    return alumnosList;
}
```

Ahora, el método `cargarAlumnos()` te permite obtener los datos de todos los alumnos en una lista la que luego puedes procesar para obtener cualquier infomación, como el promedio, la nota más alta, etc. Nota que este método lo depuré un poco para ajustarlo al nuevo comportamiento.